# Webpack - Babel Error - Couldn't find preset "@babel/env" relative to directory

Tags: webpack, react-redux, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm a developer newbie. In trying to build my application I received the below error. I referenced: [Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168491/couldnt-find-preset-babel-env-reactjs) but was unable to resolve:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Couldn't find preset "@babel/env" relative to directory "/home/jdev/www/react-redux-node-elasticsearch"
at /home/jdev/www/react-redux-node-elasticsearch/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
```

This is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-env": "^2.4.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  }
```

Here is the contents of .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
      "babel-env",
      "babel-preset-env",
      "babel-preset-react"
  ]
}
```

Can someone assist with the configuration? This is very confusing for a newbie like myself and I've looked a multiple issues online and I have not been able to solve this. I think you in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: Did you try to do the solution posted in that [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51168491/2745495)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that solution and it did not resolve the issue. I tried the exact configs in package.json and .babelrc file and nothing. also tried webpack issues and I'm not able to understand what the issue is. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I think it is a version issue, so I will look into all the packages and dependencies and confirm it. I'm a newbie, is gulp or grunt more stable than webpack? It seems quite delicate for a dev tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff, you are correct it is a versioning issue. This may be an acceptable work-a-round for you for now.

In your package.json file revise your code to the following dependency versions:

```
"dependencies": {
  "babel": "^6.5.2",
  "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
  "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
  "express": "^4.14.0",
  "pug": "^2.0.0-beta6",
  "react": "^15.4.2",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
  "webpack": "^1.14.0"
}
```

Your `.babelrc` file looks fine.

Also, add the following in your webpack.config.js file to ensure you have the configurations correct here as well:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./path/to/your/app.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/js",
    filename: "bundle.min.js"
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "babel",
        query: {
            presets: ["es2015", "react"]
        }
    }]
},
  watch: true
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jessica. This worked like a charm. You are a Goddess!